# Android ListView: looping through json array to list

Tags: android

Been working on this for a few hours now, not really sure how i should be going about sorting through my test array. I've tried a few different options i have seen posted this one is about the simplest to implement into my project. any suggestions or ideas that might help me get over this hump?

**JSON Array from php**

```
{
    "Questions": {
        "0001": {
            "Title": "What is Stackoverflow",
            "Answer": "C",
            "User": "testUSER",
            "Date": "0000-00-00",
            "Used": "0"
        },
        "0002": {
            "Title": "What is Stackoverflow",
            "Answer": "C",
            "User": "testUSERb",
            "Date": "0000-00-00",
            "Used": "1"
        },
        "0003": {
            "Title": "What is Stackoverflow",
            "Answer": "C",
            "User": "testUSERc",
            "Date": "0000-00-00",
            "Used": "0"
        }
    },
    "Count-start": 1,
    "Count-end": 3
}
```

Used: 0 = not been used 1 = user has used. I will use that to determine whether or not to show the user the question and answer.

**Helper Class**

```
public JSONObject query(){
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000);
        HttpResponse response;
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(QUERY_LINK);
        post.setHeader("json", json.toString());
        StringEntity se;
        try {
            se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
            se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json"));
            post.setEntity(se);
            response = client.execute(post);
            if (response != null) {
                InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
                a = convertStreamToString(in);
                JSONObject check = new JSONObject(a);   
                return check;
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return json;
    }
```

**Main Activity**

```
private ArrayList<ListHelper> GetSearchResults(){
        JSONObject getJSON = new Helper().query();
        JSONArray jArrayObject = new JSONArray();
        jArrayObject.put(getJSON);
        int end = 0,start = 0;
        String title, answer, user, used;
        ListHelper sr = new ListHelper();


     ArrayList<ListHelper> results = new ArrayList<ListHelper>();
     JSONObject offerObject = null;
        try {
            offerObject = getJSON.getJSONObject("Questions");
            start = offerObject.getInt("Count-start");
            end = offerObject.getInt("Count-end");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


     for(int a = start; a < end; a = a++) {
         try {


            JSONObject businessObject = offerObject.getJSONObject("Id");
            // this is were i'm stuck, how to go about selecting each id

            title = businessObject.getString("Title");
            answer = businessObject.getString("Answer");
            user = businessObject.getString("User");
            used = businessObject.getString("Used");

            sr = new ListHelper();
             sr.setTitle(title);
             sr.setUser(user);
             sr.setUsed(used);
             results.add(sr);
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
     return results;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your Json data from php is not a Json Array type.. its completely Json Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the below for your purpose: define a new `DecimalFormat` outside the `for` loop

```
DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("0000");
```

Then inside the `for` loop form your `id` string using the formatter.

```
String id = myFormatter.format(a);
```

And then use the `id` for fetching the `JSONObject`

```
// this is were i'm stuck, how to go about selecting each id
JSONObject businessObject = offerObject.getJSONObject(id);
```

The above will work only if your `ids` are at max 4 digits. You can make the format dynamic by using the `"Count-end"` value instead of using hard coded `"0000"`.

All this trouble could have been avoided if `"Questions"` object were a JSONArray.